# ES6 does for of get prototype values - how to check hasownproperty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Using `for...in` I always check `hasOwnProperty` (which I guess is a good argument for using `Object.keys`) like:

```
for (let a in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
        //logic
    }
}
```

Do I need to do the same check when I use `for...of` and if so how should I do it?

According to the [MDN page on `for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

> While `for...in` iterates over property names, `for...of` iterates over property values

But it doesn't say anything about whether that iteration includes inherited properties or only instance properties. The explanation and example code given there only involve instance properties.

Comment: Why not just look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)?

Comment: "the difference between a for...of loop and a for...in loop. While for...in iterates over property names, for...of iterates over property values:"

Comment: I did, it wasn't clear from them if it iterates over own properties or not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: @Ziki Yeah, I guess that implies that it iterates over all properties. It would be nice if those docs were explicit though...,

Comment: @pQuestions123 It iterates through an object's `@@iterator`. the behavior of each object type's `@@iterator` object is defined by the ES6 specification and differs from object to object.

Comment: How difficult would it be for you to create a test case an try for yourself?

Comment: @Ziki That explanation is correct but incomplete, not merely for failing to mention how inherited properties are iterated, but also for failing to explain that `for..of` can operate differently for different objects. (The explanation and code there is narrowly specific to arrays.) We do get some kind of hint about that in the introduction about "a custom iteration hook" but no further explanation.

Comment: @hindmost I've edited the question to highlight exactly where the MDN documentation is insufficient to answer this question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`for...of` iterates through an iterable object's iterator. In the ES6 specification, the function that produces an iterator for an object is identified on an object by the `Symbol.iterator` property; i.e., `someObj[Symbol.iterator]`.

The iterator returned by `Symbol.iterator` for each iterable type is different, but generally speaking it will only iterate the values contained by the object that are meaningful relative to the type. For example:

- The [`String` iterator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype-@@iterator) iterates each code point as a single-character string
- The [`Map` iterator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-map.prototype-@@iterator) iterates over the `[[MapData]]` internal slot of the `Map`, which is where key-to-value mappings are stored
- The [`Array` iterator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype-@@iterator) only iterates over integer indexes (see [`%ArrayIteratorPrototype%.next`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-%arrayiteratorprototype%.next))

Adding properties to the object's prototype is unlikely to affect the iterator's behavior, so in that respect is not *necessary* to test if the value comes from an own-property or not.

`for..of` and `for..in` are fundamentally different. `for..in` iterates over an object's properties, and it's sometimes necessary to ask questions about those properties, like whether they are inherited or not. `for..of` pumps values out of an iterator, which privately decides what values to return in what order. It's not necessarily meaningful to ask whether the result of a `for..of` iteration is from an inherited property or not, because it might not be from a property at all. (Case in point, `for..of` iteration of a `Map` returns values that are not exposed as properties.)

---

I can think of only one (tremendously strange) case in which an inherited property would affect the behavior of an `Array` iterator, if all the following were true:

- if `Array.prototype` has a property with an integer name, and
- that integer-named property is *not* set as an own-property on the instance being iterated, *and*
- the instance's `length` is greater than that integer index's name

For example:

```
Array.prototype["7"] = "hello";   // why are you doing this?? :O
var a = [1,2,3]
a.length = 8;                     // why are you doing this?? D:
for(g of a) { console.log(g); }   // great job, you got strange results
```

In this extremely bizarre case, you would iterate over the inherited `7` property. That's literally the only case I can think of, though; other inherited properties will be ignored either because they don't have integer names, or because they're shadowed by an instance property with the same integer name, or because they are greater or equal to the instance's `length`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really enforce the same check as you don't have explicit access to the property key.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
for(let val of arr) {
  // all you have is the value
  // there is no way to check
  console.log(val);
}
```

The `for-of` statement can be used with any [iterable object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) and the way the iterable protocol is defined can vary from object to object.

The reason the `hasOwnProperty` checks are used is to make sure that the property is on the object, rather than on the prototype of the object. You can easily test whether this is the same for `for-of`.

```
var prototype = { a: 1 };
var instance = Object.create(prototype);
instance.b = 2;
instance.c = 3;

for(var val of instance) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

Different environments have differing implementations of `for-of` at the moment, it works in my browser with Arrays, but not Objects. The best thing to do is try it in the environment you want to deploy to.